# triggering .click() inside list element gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where there either can be pure text or a link inside. If a link is available, the entire list-element must be clickable. So when I do this:

```
if ($('.link').length) {
  $('li[data-contains-link]').on('click', function (e) {
      $('.link').click()    
  })
}
```

it gives me the error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: why do you call the click in the click event itself?its like throwing a some after throwing a stone it will be infinite

Comment: @guradio Thats a good point :-) I might do it differently then :-s

Comment: If you show your HTML you can get more help

Comment: may you want first stop the propagation of the click and then checkout if the list contains a link, and then go to the url?

Answer (score 0):

You are raising click event after a click event - probably a recursive call. Make sure that no `li[data-contains-link]` is a `.link`, otherwise this will make a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

$('.link') is either inside $('li[data-contains-link]')

or

some $('li[data-contains-link]') has class link.

This puts you in a loop of listening a click and then generating it on self or one of its children, thus recursions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `event.stopPropagation()` in the `.link`'s click handler:

```
 $('li[data-contains-link]').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.link').click();    
 })

$('.link').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // <---addd it here.
    console.log('.link elem clicked!!!!');    
 })
```

---

As this attribute selector `li[data-contains-link]` states that it is a parent element which does have a `.link` element. As you have bound a click event on the parent element and you are triggering the click on the child element, that makes a recursive call so causes the error: ***Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded***.

That is due to ***event bubbling***. `event.stopPropagation()` can be used to stop the event to bubble up to the parent element, so there won't be any recursive call as parent doesn't get the event.